# difficulty understanding scheme identifier

Tags: scheme, racket, predicate

I have this definition (in scheme):

```
(define identifier? symbol?)
```

what exactly does the `identifier?` predicate check? 
are integers and letters considered as symbols in scheme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement

```
(define identifier? symbol?)
```

Defines `identifier?` to be an alias for `symbol?`. After that you can use:

```
(identifier? car)   ;; #f
(identifier? 10)    ;; #f
(identifier? `abcd) ;; #t
```

Comment: I think you ment `'car`. my question is why 10 is not a symbol?

Comment: `10` is an numeric literal. `"10"` is a string literal, and `'10` is a symbol literal in scheme You can `(+ 10 10)` but not `(+ 10 '10)

Comment: @omi 10 is a constant, not a symbol.

Comment: I guess skipping chapters wasn't a cleaver thing to do... thank you!

Comment: @WorBlux Actually, `'10` and `10` are identical because they are both self-evaluating. Neither of them are symbols (`(symbol? '10)  =>  #f`). Reference: http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-15.html#node_sec_A.3 (unfortunately, I didn't find something more readable, but I think this is a result of the difference between lines containing `sym_1` and the lines containing `sqv_1` for `L_i` and `L_m`).